# Lista telefônica com banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho uma lista telefônica com o formulário já pronto e agora preciso que quando o usuário digitar no campo buscar um nome ou setor, esse valor deve ser comparado com valores do banco de dados e ser devolvido um valor que corresponde a busca dele.

Segue meu código PHP até agora;

```
$bdServidor = '';
$bdUsuario = '';
$bdsenha = '';
$bdBanco = 'lista_telefonica';

$conexao = mysqli_connect($bdServidor, $bdUsuario, $bdsenha,$bdBanco);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao))
{
    echo"problemas para conectar no banco.Verifique os dados!";
    die();
}

// Variavel que contem o valor do campo BUSCA;
$valor = $_POST['busca'];
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow em Português! Duma próxima vez tente explicar melhor a sua dúvida e o que pretende. Já tentou alguma coisa? Se sim mostre o seu código e descreve onde tem o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso terá de fazer um pesquisa ([`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)) na Base de Dados e usar o [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) para verificar se existe a palavra naquele campo.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM lista_telefonica WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor%' OR setor LIKE '%$valor%"; 

if ($result = query($conexao, $sql)) 
{
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $line =$obj->id;
        $line.=$obj->name;
    }
}
$result->close();
unset($obj);
unset($sql);
unset($query);
```

PS: Não se esqueça de usar [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) por causa do [SQL INJECTION](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda..vou estudar seu código e sobre LIKE para depois incrementar no meu programa;

Comment: De nada. O que eu fiz foi uma versão minimalista de como se faz, de qualquer forma tem aqui a informação toda de que precisa para aprender, qualquer coisas faça uma pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá usar uma *query* `SELECT` algo como isso:

```
<?php
 $consulta=$ pdo->query("SELECT nome, usuario FROM login;");

 while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{ echo "Nome: {$linha['nome']}
 - Usuário: {$linha['usuario']}
<br />"; } ?>
```

Procure mais sobre CRUD, é algo simples de fazer esse seu `SELECT`. Quanto ao comparar você deverá utilizar no `SELECT` um verificador, como um `'%LIKE'` do SQL.

Aqui tem um exemplo sobre [CRUD](http://www.devmedia.com.br/crud-com-php-pdo/28873)

Ah lembrando que no seu formulário tem que fazer o get da variável.

Siga os passos desse tutorial acima e procure saber sobre o `LIKE`.

Comment: Ele está a usar `mysqli`. E não foi o bigown que fez a pergunta.

Comment: Ok @JorgeB. De qualquer forma independente do banco de dados ele vai ter o LIKE como bem explicou abaixo e citei acima :)